# Does calling the method "SecurityUtils.getSubject();" will always hit the redis database?

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, shiro

I am implementing a redis-shiro session management feature in my project and currently I have very little information about Shiro & Redis.

I want to know whether calling the below will hit the redis database everytime to check whether any sessionId exist in the redis database or not.

**Code in Service**

```
Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
 Session session = currentUser.getSession();
```

**Code in Controller:**

```
 public String getSomrthing(@CookieValue("JSESSIONID") String fooCookie){
       callingSomeServiceMethod(fooCookie);
       return "It does not matter";
   }
```

Does we have to match the sessionId manually like below in our service or does Shiro will match it automatically, since my application will be running in a multi instance environment.?

```
Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
   if(currentUser.getId.equals(fooCookie)){
        //.....Some Code 
       //.....Some Code
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session will looked up a max of once per request, less depending on any additional caching you have configured.

You wouldn't manage/lookup the sessionId directly from your controller though.  All of this logic would be transparent and handled by Shiro and/or your servlet container's session management.